# Pan and tilt mechanism

Tags: motors, torque, friction, bearings

this is my first project that i am working on. I want to make a IR sensor mount using stepper motors.

[image]

I seen this on youtube and would like to make a similar design.

[image]

I plan on using aluminium mounting hubs to transmit the torque from the shafts to the aluminium frame as shown above. My question is how is the torque transmitted from the motors to this camera mount? Is there a bearing and if so, what kind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any bearings in there. The mounting hub held rigidly onto the motor shaft with one or two grub screw(s), and the hub itself is rigidly screwed onto the frame with the 4 threaded holes you can see in the photo. As long as the motor can provide enough torque, when the shaft turns, the rest (hub & frame) will follow. Of course, backlash is quite likely to be present, and the motor control is of paramount importance if you want a smooth, jerk-free, motion of the frame, but in essence it's pretty simple, mechanically at least.

Comment: Thank you. Quick follow up question... would using wood/plastic and glue affect the mechanics/friction much if i needed to reduce weight?

Comment: On the photos you posted, it looks like the hub and the frame are aluminium, which is normally pretty good in terms of weight vs strength compromise. The heaviest thing on here by a long shot (after the motor itself) I would say is the camera, so that's where I would focus my efforts in trying to minimise the weight.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. It is a very small IR sensor so the weight of that will be negligible compared to the frame. I'm now thinking that there will be moment force present on the bottom stepper due to the weight of the top stepper.
Maybe using wood/plastic will reduce this moment.. I don't think it will make a great deal of difference though.

Comment: I don't think so. The risk is that wood isn't strong enough to hold the weight of the motor. Engineering plastic (e.g. polyprop, acetal or delrin) might be OK, but it'll have to be a machined part with the threaded holes for mounting the hub, I wouldn't rely on glueing. I would keep the hub in aluminium.